# Spring Boot autowiring entitymanager specific to configuration

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entitymanager

So I have two configurations for `default` and `dev` and in each configuration there's a

```
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }
```

Now I want in some component to inject the `EntityManager` like so

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;
```

but I'm receiving

```
... required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - entityManager: defined by method 'entityManager' in class path resource ...
```

Why the `EntityManager` from default is not injected ???

Comment: It sounds like both of your configurations are being loaded, no? Are they controlled by profiles? How do you intend that only one is selected?

Comment: Each configuration has a @Profile("..."), also the active profile is set.

Comment: @Bart are you using `--spring.profiles.active` to mention the profile?

Comment: What happens if you remove one of the configurations? Is it actually that Spring is providing you a default, and that's being picked up?

Comment: When I remove the second one the problem is the same. Only `@Primary` works.

Answer (score 2):

Are `default` and `dev` maven profiles? If yes then you should choose a configuration for every profile with using `@Profile`

```
@Profile("dev")
@Configuration
public class DevConfig
```

Or, the second way - mark one of beans as primary:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@Autowired
public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
```